# How to troubleshoot the mkorder Error: Store-and-forward server clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

How would you troubleshoot the multisite error message:

```
---- NOTE: consult log file (/var/adm/rational/clearcase/log/shipping_server_log) for errors.
mkorder(2232326): Error: Store-and-forward server "/opt/rational/clearcase/etc/shipping_server" failed with status 1
```

We are not able tsync the vob as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the log and the *following* error message after this one.
As seen in "[Removing the default Storage Class](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21247712)", that error message can be followed by the actual cause.

One possible cause in described in "[shipping_server RPC fails sending packets to a store and forward host](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21429858)":

> There is a defect in the DNS algorithms used.
>   When the VOB server initiates an export, there is a request sent to the local DNS server for information on the reachability of the destination.
>   If the DNS server is busy or takes too long to reply, then the packet(s) get stalled in the outgoing bay even though the shipping server would have been able to forward them along.